# duplicate view of debugger window on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, assembly

I would like to have 2 instance of the "machine code" view on the Visual Studio debugger

[image]

Someone can help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not find the better answer, it just opens one "Machine Code/Disassembly" window if we debug one app just with one VS instance in default. If we want to get two windows, we often debug projects using two VS instance.

I help you submit a feature request to the product team:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32528791-duplicate-view-of-debugger-window-on-visual-studio

If possible, you could add your comment and vote this user voice.

Comment: So you can attach two debuggers to the same process?

Comment: We can't attach 2 debuggers to 1 process. Actually I mean that just debug the same project but saved in different folders. Not a nice workaround for this issue, that's the reason I submit a feature request to the product team directly.

Comment: Ok, so you could usefully look at disassembly or static constant data in the 2nd instance, and use the "primary" instance to look at where you're actually single-stepping, or at runtime-variable memory.  (On Linux I'd just tab over to another terminal and use `disas foo.o | less` (where that's an alias for `objdump -drwC -Mintel`).  But if I was used to a GUI IDE/debugger, yeah it sounds useful to use your usual environment instead of a separate tool.